# Google plus button creating horizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-plus-one

I had no problems adding a Facebook/Twitter sharing buttons but right now Google+ is driving me crazy, WHEREVER i put this code on my page (using Bootstrap grid), i get a 2-3 pixels on the right creating an horizontal scrollbar:

```
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-align="left" data-annotation="none"></div>
```

Plus Script code at the bottom of my page:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>{lang: 'fr'}</script>
```

Any idea how to fix it? I've tried to put my div in another div with fixed width and stuff like that but no effect, the script is replacing the div and forcing all css regardless my attempts ... i have no idea what is replacing the original div and how to work on it.

I'm a bit lost here, help welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and this worked for me:

```
iframe[id^="oauth2relay"]{
    display: none!important;
}
```

Taken from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vYfnZ_XB8M

Answer (score 0):

Try inspect the button and find out which element has the scrollbar and add this CSS on it.

overflow: visible;

Comment: The scrollbar is on the whole page, it's not an a specific element.I repeat: it does not matter where i put the mentionned DIV element on my page, it adds 3-4 pixels on the right of my Bootstrap grid and creates a scrollbar on the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem

```
iframe[id^="oauth2relay"] { position: fixed !important; }
```

G+ button adds an iframe.